# Getting ORA-01109 error "Database not open"

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to run a script in SQL Developer and getting this error. What's strange is I've run this same script before with no issues and I haven't changed any settings since then. Is there a fix that does not involve the command line or UNIX (as I don't know how to use either...)

Comment: You should provide more information about your issue in order to other people can reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

If "waiting" doesn't help you'll might need to go to the commandline ( or in this case better ask your database-administrator to do so).

At least you have to connect as sysdba to try an "alter database open". After that you may get a more detailed information about your problem.

Starting up an oracle database goes from shutdown -> nomount -> mount -> open. To be open all database files and redologs musst be checked and consistent, if thats not the case the database will not open.

Cause may be a shutdown abort for example, a media recovery might be necessary.

More Details, for example here:

http://books.google.de/books?id=Xkbl0Prv83cC&pg=PA143&lpg=PA143&dq=oracle+states+shutdown+nomount+mount+open&source=bl&ots=FByVfgaiNr&sig=yuLXW_OW3uikkaVBEhTSaDM9WbY&hl=de&sa=X&ei=ZltRVNeuE6TmyQPp54DwDg&ved=0CD8Q6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=oracle%20states%20shutdown%20nomount%20mount%20open&f=false